# How to remove label for multiple Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts

I have thousands of contacts with automatically create labels from each import in the past I did.

I understood how to remove labels for a single contact, but how can I do this bulk on multiple contacts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way. Alternatively you can:

1. Click on the 3 dots on the top right side `Change column order` and rearrange the columns bringing `Labels` closer to the beginning.

[image: order]

2. On the bottom right hand side go under the `More actions` dropdown, where you'll find the `Export` and `Import` options. Export as `.csv`

[image: more]

3. Create a new label (e.g. `backup`) and add ALL your contacts in it.
4. Open the downloaded `.csv` file in a spreadsheet and edit to your liking (using formulas).
5. Import your new, edited file.
6. By now you have duplicates of all your contacts. Select the label `backup` and delete all contacts in it. Delete the label.
7. Enjoy your bulk edited contacts.

*PS: If you don't feel comfortable deleting the contacts you can use the `Duplicates` and `Merge` functionalities after the import.*

Comment: Thank you, it seems a good workaround

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to delete a label for all the contacts with that label, it looks like you can delete an entire label without affecting the contacts themselves. Simply mouse over it, and click the trash icon. 
[image]

It will give you an option to delete either the label and keep the contacts, or delete the label and delete the contacts.

[image]